# What are the pitches in this donso ngoni tuning?

Tags: tuning, pitch, clefs

Please see the image below depicting the [donso ngoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngoni_(instrument)).

[image: donso ngoni tuning]

I'm bad at identifying notes from clefs. But if I'm giving a try to guess the notes I think in the key of A: it is A - B - D - E - G - A. Is that correct?

What are the pitches and notes from the image above?

Answer (score 1):

The pitches, from left to right, are:

`B`, `E`, `A`, `G` or `G#`, `D`, `A`

[image: Donso Ngosi tuning with pitches labeled]

Comment: Thank you, Aaron! Regardless what the key is whether the root note is B or C, etc., the arrangements of notes are still the same. Like if it is in the key of B it is B-C#-E-F#-A-B. Correct?

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah It's not clear what you're asking. When you say "root note", do you mean the lowest pitch? If yes, then to keep all of the strings tuned in the same way relative to each other, the tuning, in the left-to-right order given in the chart, would be C#-F#-B-A or A#-E-B. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by B - C# - E - F# - A or A# - B is the arrangement of notes in ascending order, if we play it on the piano or maybe a guitar note by note. Yes, I'm talking about the lowest note of the scale or in a key regarding the "root note".